# Couldn't destroy QGIS Custom Edit Form Factories

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I created custom form factories using [this tutorial](http://blog.vitu.ch/10142013-1847/write-your-own-qgis-form-elements#comment-123). However, the factory destructor [`QgsEditorWidgetRegistry()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsEditorWidgetRegistry.html#af20e4a9d2ee43e652aaa346feb504c2f). However, it doesn't destroy them. I just used the above destructor at the beginning of the creation of factories like this but there is no effect.

```
QgsEditorWidgetRegistry() # Destroy existing factories
myFactory = WidgetWrapperFactory()
QgsEditorWidgetRegistry.instance().registerWidget( "MyRuleWidget", myFactory )
```

Is there anything that I am missing or is it a QGIS bug?

Comment: How did you "use the above destructor"?
What is the ultimate goal? Remove a widget type?

Comment: Dear Mattias, I am using the code in a plugin. In case the plugin reloads accidentally or through plugin reloader, when trying to re-register the factories, it couldn't load the widgets in the form. So to avoid that, I wanted to first destroy, and then create it. But the main thing is, the destructor is not working even from QGIS python console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor you linked to above is for cleaning up the registry once when QGIS ends and it's nothing python code should care about (or can even access).

What you are looking for is an `unregisterWidget` function, which is not available at the moment. You can open a feature request for that.

For now, just try not re-registering the factory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Matthias! I have implimented a mechanism to check on registered factories and not to add them if they are in `WidgetWrapperFactory().factories()`. However, once the plugin reloads, the existing factories fail to work.

Comment: Did you try to keep a reference to the factory somewhere outside your plugin code? I guess some part of the factory gets deleted on reload but not sure if and how a workaround to that will look.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I tried a script global variable before but let me try again using a plugin global variable. I will report back the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still didn't work even though existing factories are not recreated.